# Prevent value change in html

Tags: php, html

is there any other method to prevent someone changing the value and enable the check box?

```
<input required="true" value="10" readonly="true" id="field_limit_pages" name="field_limit_pages" type="text">
<input disabled="" name="field_repeat_check" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: who having permission to change? dont get your question

Comment: @nobleman, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: PHP is server-side. Forms are dealt with Client-Side. So, the effective answer to your question is No, with PHP you cannot ensure that someone doesn't use javascript to enable the checkbox other than checking your input before updating any database this may be connected to.

Comment: nothing that won't be ridiculous

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: if its loaded by the browser and the user manipulates the dom from there, then no, you cannot prevent that

Comment: is there possible to store value in php array and use print function?

Comment: @nobleman   yes, it is possible.

Comment: using jQuery you can achieve this.

Comment: @ punitha subramani @ WhiteAngelhi, the code above has disabled the fields, but with firefox or chromed any use can enable the fields, my question is there any method could prevent that to happen?

Comment: @ northkildonan could you show me how? or is there any tutorial out there?